# Can UPDATE be written in different way?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've been trying and trying to work out how I can make this `UPDATE` query simpler and it's got to the point where I can't figure it out.

I want to be able to achieve changing `school_id_2` or `school_id_3` or `school_id_4` to zero if they equal the `id` in this case is 25. I want to be able to do this without running all the separate updates.

Is it possible to do this in one single `UPDATE`?

Query:

```
$query = "
    UPDATE      pupil_blog_quad_overview,
                pupil_blog_quad 
            SET pupil_blog_quad_overview.accepted = '0',
                pupil_blog_quad_overview.school_id = '0',
                pupil_blog_quad_overview.updated = NOW()
        WHERE   pupil_blog_quad_overview.school_id = '25' AND 
                pupil_blog_quad_overview.group_id = '58';

    UPDATE      pupil_blog_quad_overview,
                pupil_blog_quad
            SET pupil_blog_quad.school_id_2 = '0',
                pupil_blog_quad.updated = NOW()
        WHERE   pupil_blog_quad.school_id_2 = '25' AND
                pupil_blog_quad_overview.group_id = '58';

    UPDATE      pupil_blog_quad_overview,
                pupil_blog_quad 
            SET pupil_blog_quad.school_id_3 = '0',
                pupil_blog_quad.updated = NOW()
        WHERE   pupil_blog_quad.school_id_3 = '25' AND
                pupil_blog_quad_overview.group_id = '58';

    UPDATE      pupil_blog_quad_overview,
                pupil_blog_quad 
            SET pupil_blog_quad.school_id_4 = '0',
                pupil_blog_quad.updated = NOW()
        WHERE   pupil_blog_quad.school_id_4 = '25' AND
                pupil_blog_quad_overview.group_id = '58'";
```

Comment: What's wrong with separate updates?

Comment: @Jocelyn Just wondering if there was a way of doing it all in one update, just to have shorter query and cleaner.

Comment: If you are ready to sacrifice performance just to save a few bytes of code on your disk, yes it is possible, look at the answers.

Comment: @Jocelyn , Did below answers take more time then executing three separate quries ...?

Comment: @Jocelyn - You're correct, the performance is a little slower than separated queries.

Comment: @Hemakumar - The performance is a little better with separate queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with two updates , not one since your are updating two different tables.

The 3 updates can be done with one query using `CASE EXPRESSION`:

```
UPDATE pupil_blog_quad_overview, pupil_blog_quad
   SET pupil_blog_quad_overview.accepted  = '0',
       pupil_blog_quad_overview.school_id = '0',
       pupil_blog_quad_overview.updated   = NOW()
 WHERE pupil_blog_quad_overview.school_id = '25'
   AND pupil_blog_quad_overview.group_id = '58';


UPDATE pupil_blog_quad_overview, pupil_blog_quad
   SET  pupil_blog_quad.updated = NOW()
        ,pupil_blog_quad.school_id_2 = CASE WHEN pupil_blog_quad.school_id_2 = '25' THEN '0' ELSE pupil_blog_quad.school_id_2 END
        ,pupil_blog_quad.school_id_3 = CASE WHEN pupil_blog_quad.school_id_3 = '25' THEN '0' ELSE pupil_blog_quad.school_id_3 END
        ,pupil_blog_quad.school_id_4 = CASE WHEN pupil_blog_quad.school_id_4 = '25' THEN '0' ELSE pupil_blog_quad.school_id_4 END 
 WHERE pupil_blog_quad_overview.group_id = '58'
   AND '25' in(pupil_blog_quad.school_id_2,pupil_blog_quad.school_id_3,pupil_blog_quad.school_id_4)
```